# awslogs agent create zombie process repeatly

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

i'm running [awslogs agent](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/AgentReference.html) on a ubuntu 16.

when i start awslogs agent, two process was created.

```
$ sudo systemctl start awslogs
root     25973     1  0 Feb13 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh /var/awslogs/bin/awslogs-agent-launcher.sh --start --background --pidfile --user awslogs --chuid awslogs &
root     25976 25973  0 Feb13 ?        02:16:01 /var/awslogs/bin/python /var/awslogs/bin/aws logs push --config-file /var/awslogs/etc/awslogs.conf --additional-configs-dir /var/awslogs/etc/config
```

and, when i stop awslogs, only one process killed. other one process still alive.

```
$ sudo systemctl stop awslogs
root     25976 25973  0 Feb13 ?        02:16:01 /var/awslogs/bin/python /var/awslogs/bin/aws logs push --config-file /var/awslogs/etc/awslogs.conf --additional-configs-dir /var/awslogs/etc/config
```

when i start awslogs agent again, two process created. so whole process count is 3.

Answer (score 0):

I've met a same problem.

```
root@ip-192-168-101-176:~# ps -ef |grep aws
root       500 32151  0 16:17 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto aws
root     31644     1  0 16:02 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh /var/awslogs/bin/awslogs-agent-launcher.sh --start --background --pidfile --user awslogs --chuid awslogs &
root     31645 31644  0 16:02 ?        00:00:06 /var/awslogs/bin/python /var/awslogs/bin/aws logs push --config-file /var/awslogs/etc/awslogs.conf --additional-configs-dir /var/awslogs/etc/config
```

process id "31644" is the zombie process.

I'm considering whether to use below shell program on crond.

```
 kill $(ps -ef |egrep "\/var\/awslogs\/bin\/python \/var\/awslogs\/bin\/aws logs push --config-file \/var\/awslogs\/etc\/awslogs.conf --additional-configs-dir \/var\/awslogs\/etc\/config"|awk '{ ppid=$3; if (ppid==1) print $2}')
```

this shell program kills the awslogs process if this parent process nomber is 1.

I do not assume any responsibility.